# How to determine maximum positive base-10 value of a float mantissa?

Tags: c, floating-point, permutation, ieee-754

While trying to understand `int`, if I was given the size of int in bits, I could use the formula of permutations to determine the maximum positive and negative base-10 values of int. So if a signed int is 16 bits wide, I can use 2^16 to determine the number of possible permutations and then can calculate the maximum number of positive numbers and the maximum number of negative numbers by using 2^15.

In a 32 bit float, 24 bits are assigned for the significand and its sign. 2^23 would be the maximum number of permutations, if we consider the sign to be positive. How can I get the maximum value of the significand from this number 2^23? Or is my understanding of floating point numbers flawed?

Answer (score 3):

[ieee-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) uses *significand* rather than *mantissa*.

C does not define mantissa.  C uses *significand*.

Common [`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) normal<sup>1</sup> values have a 24-bit significand that is made up of 1 implied bit with a value of 1 and 23 explicitly encoded binary fractional bits.     All 2<sup>24</sup> combination are possible.

The maximum *significand* is 1.11111111 11111111 1111111<sub>2</sub> or 1.99999988079071044921875<sub>10</sub> or (2.0-2<sup>-23</sup>).

When this is combined with the maximum binary exponent for finite numbers 2<sup>(254-127)</sup>,  the maximum `float`, `FLT_MAX` is 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0 or about 3.402823466e+38.

---

<sup>1</sup>For sub-numerals, there is no implied bit.

That maximum *significand* is 0.11111111 11111111 1111111<sub>2</sub> or 0.99999988079071044921875<sub>10</sub>

Comment: I have changed 'mantissa' to 'significand' in the question as per your proposal

Answer (score 3):

The number of possible values of a normal significand of a `float` is `(FLT_RADIX-1)/FLT_EPSILON`, where `FLT_RADIX` and `FLT_EPSILON` are defined by including `<float.h>`.

This is because `FLT_EPSILON` is the step size from 1 to the next greater representable number, so it is a change of 1 in the significand bits (when they are interpreted as a binary integer and we are starting from the floating-point number 1.000…000). `FLT_RADIX/FLT_EPSILON` calculates how many steps the significand could go through, starting from 0, until it wraps or overflows its leading digit. However, we do not start at zero; the question requests excluding the implicit leading 1 bit. The leading bit of a normalized binary-based floating-point number is 1, but, when we generalize to other bases, the leading digit of a floating-point number may be something other than 1 for a normalized number; it can be a non-zero integer less than `FLT_RADIX`. So, starting from 1 instead of 0, there are `(FLT_RADIX-1)/FLT_EPSILON` possible values of normal significands.

Note that `(FLT_RADIX-1)/FLT_EPSILON` has an integer value but floating-point type. To use it as an integer type, you may need a cast, such as when printing it with `%d`.

The floating-point number with the same scale (exponent) as 1 but the maximum significand is `FLT_RADIX - FLT_EPSILON`. The maximum value of the significand as an integer is `FLT_RADIX/FLT_EPSILON - 1`. Note that the latter includes the leading digit.

### Notes

“Significand” is the preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point number. “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. Significands are linear; multiplying a significand multiplies the number represented. Mantissas are logarithm; adding to a mantissa multiplies the number represented.

“Permutation” refers to moving things around; (1 2 3 4) and (3 4 2 1) are permutations of each other. You appear to want the number of different values the significand bits can have.

Comment: You are right, I was indeed referring to the number of different values the significand bits can have, however I was hoping to learn if it was possible to determine the maximum and minimum base-10 value a float can contain from that number of permutations, i.e. 2^23, as it is possible to determine the maximum and minimum base-10 values of int and int based types from the number of values the bits can hold.

Comment: @Monke: Do you want the maximum finite value a `float` can represent, rather than just the maximum value its significant can have? That value is `FLT_RADIX-FLT_EPSILON` multiplied by `FLT_RADIX` to the power of `FLT_MAX_EXP-1`. (The `-1` is due to the C standard handling the significand a bit unusually.) The C standard library has a function for “`x` multiplied by `FLT_RADIX` to the power of `n`”; it is `scalbnf(x, n)`, so the maximum finite value `float` can represent is `scalbnf(FLT_RADIX-FLT_EPSILON, FLT_MAX_EXP-1)`. `<float.h>` defines a macro with this value, `FLT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of the mantissa has no meaning without considering the exponent. What the 23 tells you is that the number of significant decimal digits is `23 * log(2)` ≈ 7.

However a 24th bit is implied, giving `24 * log(2)` which is > 7. So all 7-digit integer values can be stored without loss of precision.

Also, any integer that has a power of 2 as a factor, and when divided by that factor has 7 digits or less, can also be exactly represented, as the power of 2 is taken up by the exponent (subject to the limit of the exponent value).

So it is the exponent size that gives the *range* of values that can be stored, while the mantissa (significand) size gives the *precision*.